# Title not showing in tkinter spawned window

Tags: python-3.x

The problem appears to be that tkinter is using white for the window control bar AND white as the text color for the title (so you never see the default title of Tk at the top of the window). I've also tried using the title method to set a title name but same result ... everything is white.  I stumbled across the name actually being there when I performed an ALT-TAB to view all the windows I had running and there the spawned window was with the proper title being displayed.  As soon as that window is selected and brought to the active window, the white color takes over and the title disappears.  The window controls (min, max, close) are showing and working just fine.

**Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Nothing Shows')
root.mainloop()
```

I'm running this on a Chromebook with Linux enabled:

DELL 14 2-IN-1   4/128  Ram/SSD

**Software Used:**

```
Python Version: 
Shipped with  2.7.16
Upgraded to Python 3x
3.7.3  a/o 12/2019 18:57:59
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
robosmr@penguin:~$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
```

**TKINTER Version:**

```
This is Tcl/Tk version 8.6.9
```

**Sublime Text Editor:**

```
Version 3.2.2  Build 3211
```

From several posts there doesn't appear to be any means to configure or set the foreground or background colors (fg= or bg=) of the control bar without jumping through hoops and writing a customized bar.